# Supporting both FD-number and filename parameterized redirections

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

I am writing a shell script that redirects the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` output of a program. The destination of the redirect is a variable. Usually, the destination is a file in which case the following works fine.

```
simple_redirect()
{
  myfunc=$1
  myfile=$2

  myfunc &>myfile
}
simple_redirect ls text.txt
```

However, sometimes I don't want to redirect to a file, but want to print to `STDOUT` like normal.
If `myfile` is `&1` for `STDOUT`, I get the following error:
`$myfile: ambiguous redirect`

If I run the command
`ls &>&1`, I see: `parse error near '&'`.

I have thought of a workaround by redirecting `STDOUT` and `STDERR` separately: `ls 1>&1 2>&1`. However, I like this option less because I have to reuse the variable and it is less readable. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Which **precise** shell? Not just which shell, but which *release*? POSIX doesn't specify `&>` at all, and ability to use a variable with an FD number on the right-hand side of a redirection in bash is a recent (4.x-series) extension.

Comment: BTW, what does `&>&1` do that `2>&1` does not? `1>&1` is completely redundant, after all -- stdout *already* supports to stdout, by definition.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `&>"$myfile"`, by the way? That's a very different thing than `&>myfile`.

Comment: BTW, you *really* want to put the filename as the first argument, and the function name after -- that way you can have the function's arguments directly follow its name.

Comment: ...it's funny, btw, to have something only tagged `shell` (which usually implies that answers should be POSIX-compatible rather than targeting any more specific shell implementation) when the `&>` practice used isn't itself POSIX-compatible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bash 4.1 or newer, the following will work:

```
redirect_to() {
  local myfile=$1; shift
  case $myfile in
    -)    "$@" ;;
    "&"*) "$@" >&${myfile#"&"} 2>&1 ;;
    *)    "$@" >"$myfile"      2>&1 ;;
  esac
done

redirect_to -           ls -l foo.d/ # no redirection
redirect_to &2          ls -l foo.d/ # redirection to FD 2
redirect_to foo.list    ls -l foo.d/ # redirection to foo.list
redirect_to /dev/stdout ls -l foo.d/ # consider doing this anyhow
```

`>&$foo` is a bash 4.1 extension which allows a variable to be used to provide a file descriptor number -- prior to this, you'd need to use `>/dev/fd/${foo#"&"}` instead (if your operating system provides them; given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag on the question, this should be a generally safe assumption).

---

If you don't have bash 4.1 or newer (and particularly if you're targeting POSIX sh rather than bash altogether), you can't implement the `>&$foo` option without `eval` -- a primitive which [has substantial security caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) -- and are better off using `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/stderr`, `/dev/fd/1`, etc.

To do so safely with older versions of bash might look something like this, using `printf %q` to sanitize literal arguments and `%d` to ensure that the file descriptor can only be numeric:

```
"&"*) printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"
      printf -v redir_suffix '>&%d' "${myfile#"&"}"
      eval "$cmd_str $redir_suffix 2>&1" ;;
```